# Angular 9 material components issue

Tags: angular-material, angular9

There is a material.modules.ts file with the following content

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModules {}
```

This module is then imported on the app.module.ts
On another component there is the code provided from angular material from here https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples

But when the page is loaded there are the following warnings in the console

[image: Console Warnings]

And the same goes to the node console for example

```
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: you need to add all this modules into imports array aslo